# How do I get the Settings System email Address?

Tags: templating, emails

From a template or a plugin, how can I get the value of admin/Settings/System Email Address ?
Thanks for your help
Nicolas

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get this in a template like so:

```
{# returns an array of your email settings #}
{% set settings = craft.systemSettings.email %}

{# returns the email address #}
{{ settings.emailAddress }}
```

And in a plugin you can do:

```
craft()->systemSettings->getSetting('email', 'emailAddress')
```

Answer (score 3):

In craft 3 it appears you can access it by doing the following:

`{{ craft.systemSettings.email.fromEmail }}`

Answer (score 3):

The `craft.systemSettings` variable was been deprecated as of Craft 3.1.0, and [removed in Craft 4.0](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#removed-2).

Here's how to get the system email address in Craft 3.1.0+:

```
{{ craft.app.projectConfig.get('email').fromEmail }}
```

Important: If your system email is set to an environment variable (e.g. like `$SYSTEM_EMAIL_ADDRESS`), you can use the [`parseEnv()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/functions.html#parseenv) Twig function to render it:

```
{{ parseEnv(craft.app.projectConfig.get('email').fromEmail) }}
```

Other email settings such as `replyToEmail` and `fromName` are also available via `craft.app.projectConfig.get('email')`, and can be access and used in the same way as the `fromEmail`.

Alternatively, email settings can be accessed via the `App` helper class, although it is generally discouraged to instantiate the `App` helper class from Twig:

```
{% set appHelper = create('craft\\helpers\\App') %}
{{ appHelper.mailSettings.fromEmail }}
```

Or in PHP:

```php
$fromEmail = App::mailSettings()->fromEmail;
```